# create searchable multiplatform html application without using database tools

Tags: html, forms, search, multiplatform

I want to create a searchable multiplatform (Win, Linux, MaOS) html application within a cd-rom. When the cd-rom will be launched, a simple html page will appear with a search form.
This multiplatform application (or script) will be responsible to search in a folder inside the cd (containing some pdf files) and return the corresponding pdf file according to query criteria.

In other words, I have 100 pdf files inside a folder in a cd-rom and I want an application to search inside this folder and give me the corresponding pdf file, according to my queries criteria.

Is it possible to do this, without using mysql or other database tools? Maybe creating a java applet to run simultaneously when cd-rom will be launched?